# How to populate 2D array (Matrix) from input txt taken from args?

Tags: java, matrix, input, args

My brain has probably stopped working so I really need your help with this.

So, I have an input txt file formatted like this:

```
3  //Number of Heroes (nodes lets say)
43 43 // left int = hp, right int = damage etc...
22 444
12 43  
2 //Number of enemies
20 39 //likewise with the heroes

//The latter (enemies) is not yet implemented, cause I am stuck with the    
//first part (so let's say the part before '2' is present in the input
//txt at the moment
```

My main is this (I want to be able to take multiple files in the future):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Q2 ks = new Q2();
    int length = args.length;
    for (int i = 0; length > 0; i++) {
        ks.readFile(args[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

And this is my readFile(), where I am trying to populate the matrix with the data (but failing miserably because my brain has really stopped working):

```
public int[][] readFile(String inputName) {
    BufferedReader reader;
int Matrix[][] = null;

    try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputName));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    int numberOfHeroes = Integer.parseInt(line);
    Matrix = new int[numberOfHeroes][2];
    line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(numberOfHeroes);

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHeroes; i++) {
                    int hitpoints = 0;
                    int damage = 0;
                    //while (line != null) {
                            String splittedLine[] = line.split(" ");
                            //while (splittedLine[1] != null){
                                    hitpoints = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[0]);
                                    damage = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[1]);
                                    Matrix[i][0] = hitpoints;
                                    Matrix[i][i+1] = damage;
                                    line = reader.readLine();
                            //}
                    //}

            }


            System.out.println("====GRAPH====");
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHeroes; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            System.out.print(Matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
                    System.out.println();
                }
    System.out.println("============");

        } catch(IOException e) {
    return null;
        }

    return Matrix;
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe what's wrong with your code? Do you get an error? Or is it populating the array with wrong numbers?

Comment: @embie27 The array is populated with wrong numbers. Something is wrong. I want it to display the array like: 43  43, next line:  22 444 etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the `damage` value into the wrong cell. Instead of `Matrix[i][i+1] = damage;` you want to do `Matrix[i][1] = damage;`.